# BooleanBuilder clause generating longer sql query

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I need to select items from a list of phone numbers which can have null value for some phone nos. The BooleanBuilder clause I am currently using is :

```
clause.and(QDashboard.dashboard.phoneList.any().number.isNull().
                    or(QDashboard.dashboard.phoneList.any().number.in(numbers)));
```

and the SQL query generated for the above clause is:

```
AND ( EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM phone_list pl
  WHERE parent.id         =pl.recordid
  AND ( pl.number IS NULL )
  )
OR EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM phone_list p2
  WHERE parent.id         =p2.recordid
  AND ( p2.number IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) )
  )
```

I have noticed that this query is slower for large data-sets and would be faster if the SQL was something like this :

```
AND ( EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM phone_list pl
  WHERE parent.id         =pl.recordid
  AND ( pl.number IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
  OR pl.number IS NULL)
  ));
```

How can I modify the BooleanBuilder clause to generate SQL query in the above format ?